# Is the freezing of water on atomic level a gradual process or is there also a big change?

Tags: thermodynamics, water, phase-transition, liquid-state

When you look at water that is going to freeze at $0$ °C once it looks totally different and it gets hard. So from our point of view it became suddenly another substance. But is this also on atomic level? Are the hydrogen bonds also suddenly at $0$ °C getting a change in position that is more different than changes of the bonds at other temperatures (for example from $3$ to $2$ °C)? Or is there not really a difference in change at $0$ °C and does it only look so for us observers?

Answer (score 0):

> Are the hydrogen bonds also suddenly at zero degree C getting a change in position that is more different than changes of the bonds at other temperatures (for example from 3 to 2 degree)?

Progress down from say 5 degrees Celsius to O degrees Celsius is on a discrete energy basis, and there is a phase change as liquid goes to solid ice crystals. There is obviously going to be a distribution in the rate of change of phase in some molecules, because of the difference in energy levels of the liquid molecules, but once an ice crystal forms, it sets off the rest of the liquid molecules to transform pretty quickly.

[image]

So on atomic level, as you can see from the picture above, there is far more regularity, (and therefore less entropy) in the ice, as the bonds between the molecules of ice are constrained within a much narrower range of energy distribution than water.

You can follow the entropy calculations here. [Entropy of Water and Ice](http://www.4college.co.uk/a/O/entsurr.php)

So yes, they are moving into a physically different, and regular,  position moving from the energy level that prevents the ice from forming, to the energy level at which the crystals can form, than they would undergo dropping from 3 degrees Celsius to 2 degrees Celsius.

Answer (score 0):

All depends upon the temperature difference.
If the temperature difference is high (if water is poured in liquid nitrogen at room temperature) then it will freeze quickly.

But when the temperature difference is low water freezes gradually, the water surface will freeze from outer surface and then freezing will propagate inside the water surface.

In this process the oxygen molecule must dissipate the heat to the hydrogen molecule as it is much bigger molecule than hydrogen and then the heat will help the hydrogen to get proper bonding and orientation.

If a foreign particle is present in the water then it will initiate the freezing first.